# How to focus on the wrong text field if validation fails

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have done a form with jquery validation. It is not validated if validation function is not satisfied with conditions. Now, I need to focus on the error input field after validation fails.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far.

Comment: _“I have done a form with jquery validation.”_ - then _show_ us what you got. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Just I need the logic to focus on the error field on clicking submit.There is no code error at all. but the code does not satisfy requirement of validation. That is why i need to focus on the field after submitting.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the existing code as a [mre], and then carefully list what validation rules you want to use and the missing behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="username"/>
```

in jQuery

```
$( "#username" ).focus();
```

Comment: make sure jquery lib included.